# Is it possible to call multiple endpoints in a controller test

Tags: magento2.3.2, integration-test

I am implementing a controller test, where I add some product to the cart and want to check its price:

It looks like I can call dispatch only once?

```
$this->dispatch('custom/add/?foo=bar');

$this->assertRedirect($this->stringContains('checkout/cart'));

$this->setUp();
$this->dispatch('checkout/cart');
$this->assertRegExp('#<span class="price">.*999\.00</span>#', $this->getResponse()->getBody());
```

I already tried to call setUp to clear the state, but still the first action seems to be called on the second dispatch call.

EDIT:

```
\Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getInstance()->reinitialize();
```

is also not helping